# Find all pairs such that $x^2 y + x + y$ is divisible by $xy^2 + y + 7$

Tags: number-theory

> Find all pairs $(x, y)$ of positive integers such that $x^2 y + x + y$ is divisible by $xy^2 + y + 7$. If there are too many to write, write a generic form.

I was thinking of rewriting the divisibility in a simpler way such as $xy^2 + y + 7\mid x^2 y + x + y \implies xy^2 + y + 7\mid x^2y-xy^2+x-y$ but I am not sure if that helps. Is there an easier way?

Comment: To get an infinite list of candidates, note that if our divisibility condition holds then $xy^2+y+7$ divides $x^2y^2+xy+y^2$.  I would not be surprised if that gets them all, by a size argument.

Comment: @AndréNicolas How does that generate infinite amount of solutions? $x^2y^2 + xy + y^2$ wouldn't satisfy the wanted form for a number, right?

Comment: Michael has written an answer that uses the same trick.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I get his answer, but I still can't get how we'll obtain infinite amount of solutions.

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't read your comment before posting.

Comment: @Michael: Please undelete! I have no intention of writing an answer.

Comment: @Stefan4024: If we make $y^2=7x$, that says $x=7t^2$, $y=7t$. Now check that this satisfies the original divisibility condition.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:
$$\begin{array}{ccc}xy^2+y+7&|&x^2y+x+y\\
xy^2+y+7&|&x^2y^2+xy+y^2\\
xy^2+y+7&|&y^2-7x
\end{array}$$
Compare $y^2-7x$ with $xy^2+y+7$

Comment: So it never divides since $xy^2+y+7 > y^2-7x$?

Comment: Either $y^2-7x\geq xy^2+y+7$, or $y^2-7x=0$, or $y^2-7x\leq-(xy^2+y+7)$

Comment: $(x,y)$ are positive so it can only be $xy^2+y+7 > y^2-7x$.

Comment: Good, two cases to go.

Comment: Also, multiplying by $y$ isn't an equivalent step. Meaning it isn't reversible.

Answer (score 1):

We have $x=7n^2,y=7n$ as a class of solutions because then $n(xy^2+7+y)=x^2y+y+x$.

There is one other solution $x=11,y=1$, giving $xy^2+7+y=19,x^2y+y+x=7\cdot19$.

We have $y(x^2y+x+y)-x(xy^2+y+7)=y^2-7x$, so $xy^2+y+7$ must divide $y^2-7x$.

One possibility is $y^2=7x$. That implies 7 divides $y$ and hence also $x$. So we get the solutions in the first line.

Otherwise, since $y^2-7x<y^2<xy^2+y+7$ we must have $y^2<7x$. But then if $y\ge3$ we have $xy^2+y+7>9x>7x-y^2>0$ which is impossible if $xy^2+y+7$ is a factor of $7x-y^2$. So $y=1$ or 2. It is easy to check that $y=1$ gives the solution $x=11,y=1$, whilst $y=2$ does not give a solution.

Comment: That there are not many special solutions is clear, for we want $y^2-7x$ negative. So it has absolute value $\lt 7x$. But  if $y\gt 2$, then the denominator is too big.