# Determine all pairs of $(x,y)$ such that $\frac{x^2y+x+y}{xy^2+y+11}$ is an integer

Tags: number-theory

Here is a problem that I got:

> Determine all pairs of positive integer $(x,y)$ such that $\dfrac{x^2y+x+y}{xy^2+y+11}$ is an integer.

My attempt:

First notice that $(11, 11)$ is a solution. And if $\dfrac{x^2y+x+y}{xy^2+y+11}$ is an integer, then $xy^2+y+11|x^2y+x+y$. Hence $x^2y-xy^2+x-11|xy^2+y+11$.

And then I'm stuck from here. Can anyone help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Notice that $$xy^2+y+11 \mid x(xy^2+y+11)-y(x^2y+x+y)=11x-y^2$$

Then you have three cases to check: $11x-y^2=0$, $11x-y^2<0$, and $11x-y^2>0$.

Comment: But how? I still don't get it. How can I know what $(x,y)$ satisfy it say when $11x-y^2<0$?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1834750/find-all-pairs-such-that-x2-y-x-y-is-divisible-by-xy2-y-7?rq=1

Answer (score -1):

From $\dfrac{x^2 y+x+y}{x y^2+y+11}=k$ we get

$x^2 y+x+y=k x y^2+k y+11 k\quad(*)$

from which we deduce that

$x^2 y=k x y^2$ and then $x=ky$

plug this in $(*)$

$k^2 y^3+k y+y=k^2 y^3+k y+11 k$

that is $y=11k$ and then $x=11k^2$

Thus $(11k^2;\;11k)$ for any $k\in\mathbb{N};\;k>0$ satisfy the given equation

There are three more solutions that do not enter in the previous formula

$(7;\;1)$ which gives $3$

$(10;\;2)$ which gives $4$

$(121;\;1)$ which gives $111$

BTW

plugging $(11k^2;\;11k)$  in the given equation gives $k$ as result

hope this helps

Comment: Why is $x^2y=kxy^2$?

Comment: Because it is the $3-$rd degree term must be equal in the two sides. Identity of polynomials

Comment: Then how did you get the three solutions? and how do you know that they are the only ones?

Comment: I get them from a computer program. I can't prove they are the only ones. Maybe you can try